# Rspec errors in Rails app using Nitrous.io - 'cannot open shared object file'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, nitrousio

When I run `bundle exec rspec spec/` I get the following messages in the console:

```
Could not open library 'libgtkmm-2.4': libgtkmm-2.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.                                                                       
Could not open library 'libgtkmm-2.4.so': libgtkmm-2.4.so: cannot open shared object file:     No such file or directory.                                                                 
Could not open library 'libgtkmm-2.4.so.1': libgtkmm-2.4.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.                                                             
Could not open library 'libgtkmm-3.0': libgtkmm-3.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.                                                                       
Could not open library 'libgtkmm-3.0.so': libgtkmm-3.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.                                                                 
Could not open library 'libgtkmm-3.0.so.1': libgtkmm-3.0.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

But, all of the tests pass and my app works just fine. Can anyone fill me in on what may have happened? Should I just scrap this box and clone my repo into a fresh one? I'm using Ruby 2.0.0p247 and Rails 4.0.2 in a Nitrous.io box. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though unrelated (thank google for finding this), I have been trying to install Nitrogen for Ubuntu today. I get the same error. Seems like a specific GTK library has gone missing recently from either your system or your distro's repository (if you're even using Linux).

If you're using a Linux system, install the libgtkmm packages and if you're lucky enough, your missing library will be in one of those.

Use in Ubuntu this to install all of them:

> sudo apt-get install libgtkmm*

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'll give that a shot. It's just strange that a virtual machine, one that I don't even have root privileges for, would just suddenly lose a package like that. Oh well.

Comment: Maybe it got updated to some new version and removed the old ones, but that shouldn't have been the case unless the package manager messed up some dependencies. I don't know it it helps or not, but i tried to install all the similar library packages and Nitrogen still won't find the library. Weird.

Comment: Luckily, the app itself doesn't seem to rely on the package since everything works fine. Just rspec. And I can live with that. Thanks for the help.